# file_get_contents to Extract Body using Get String

Tags: php

How to extract this to php with get string?

```
<Body>
"Example"
</body>
```

Then i want only the "Example"

Output Example with File get contents -> Get string function

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to match `<body>` and `</body>` and capture the text in between:

```
<?php


// Using HEREDOC synatx for illustration
// $str = file_get_contents($file); should work as well

$str = <<<EOT
start<body>
Some text
Some more text
</body>
text after body
EOT;
$regex = "/.*<body>(.*?)<\/body>/ms";
$result = preg_match( $regex, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

See https://3v4l.org/dl2hr

**Note** This is a very restricted use of a regular expression to extract data from HTML. You shouldn't treat this as a basic example for wider use. For that you should use `DOMDocument`